# Invalid key predicate when doing PUT operation

Tags: odata, sapui5

Hi all I am having some trouble with my PUT function and getting Invalid key predicate. I have never seen this error before and don't really know what it means. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
boxId = 1;
updateBox = {};

updateBox.x = 5;
updateBox.y = 10;

sap.ui.getCore().getModel("updateBoxModel").update("/Boxes(BoxId=" + boxId      + ")", updateBox,
        null, this.successMsg, this.errorMsg);

updateBoxLog = {};

updateBoxLog.x = 5;
updateBoxLog.y = 10;

sap.ui.getCore().getModel("updateBoxModel").update("/BoxLogs(BoxId=" + boxId  + ")", updateBoxLog,
        null, null, null);
```

The first update works as it should but the second doesn't work at all. Both tables are expecting a numeric value and not sure if this helps, but BoxLogs tables primary key isn't BoxId

Answer (score 0):

If `BoxId` is an alternate key for `BoxLogs`, you're going to have to enable alternate keys on the OData service and write some supporting code. There is a [sample project on github](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataAlternateKeySamples) that should provide enough guidance.